# Shared library cloned on build history and workspace

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have many jenkins jobs using a shared library

```
@Library('my_shared_library') _
```

On the folder of each build of each project using the library, there's a local copy of it, for example:

```
jenkins/jobs/my_project/jobs/builds/10/libs/my_shared_library
```

That means, it's copied on each build's history. 
Plus, I see it also on the project's workspace, under:

```
 jenkins/workspace/my_project@libs/my_shared_library
```

On this last directory there's sometimes several copies of this, like :

```
my_shared_library
my_shared_library@2
my_shared_library@tmp
...
```

Question is, is there some special way of handling this so that there'll be less copies? Or, why's there a copy on the project's workspace and one on the build history?

This ends up creating lots of files, which caused my jenkins to run out of inodes.

Comment: I had to double check, and indeed even if you retrieve the shared library globally and load it for a pipeline there is a local copy stored in each build job. This seems contrary to intended design.